# Injectivity and surjectivity of a linear map with parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given a linear map $L_t: V \to W$ represented by the matrix:

$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    t & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & -2t & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, consider $t \in \mathbb{R}$, when $L_t$ is injective and when it is surjective?

It is injective for the values of $t$ s.t. the restriction $L_{t_{\mathbb{R^3}}}$ is s.t. $dim(Im(L_{t_{\mathbb{R^3}}}))=3=\mathbb{R^3}$ and $dim(Ker(L_{t_{\mathbb{R^3}}}))=\{0\}$. $L_t$ cannot be surjective because $dim(W)>dim(V)$. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct. Do you know how to *find* the values of t such that the kernel has dimension 0?

Comment: @Billy "Struggling" with the Gauss-Jordan elimination, I guess (?). But better ideas are welcome!